# Returning a string pointer array from a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I am trying to use a function to split a string in its separate words. The function creates an array, and I can see that the array is working in the function. My problem is when I try to return the array back to the `main` function as another `char` array.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

char *commands(char *command) {
    char *commands[30];
    int i =0;
    char *st = strtok(command, " ");
    while (st != NULL) {
        commands[i] = strsep(&st, " ");
        st = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < i; p++) {
        printf("inside the function still: i-> %d, command: %s\n", p, commands[p]);
    }
    return *commands;
}

int main(int MainArgc, char *MainArgv[]) {
    size_t size = 10;
    char *user_input;
    char *user_commands;
    int flag = 0;
    user_input = (char *)malloc(size);

    while (flag != EOF) {
        printf("witsshell> ");
        flag = getline(&user_input, &size, stdin);
        user_commands = commands(user_input);
        puts(&user_commands[1]);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Note that `*commands` is really the same as `commands[0]`. You return the first string only. A better solution is to pass the `commands` array (and its size) as arguments to the `commands` function, and then just fill it in.

Comment: On another note, a local variable named `commands` in a function named `commands`? While it's allowed, it's very confusing. Please try to avoid naming variables the same as the function the variables belong to.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the function `commands` modifies its argument string. This may pose problems, in particular, you cannot call this function with a string literal.
- you split the string on spaces only, you should also consider TABs and newlines as word separators.
- you store the word pointers into a local array without checking for overflow, which will occur if the argument string contains more than 30 words.
- you should store a null pointer at the end of the array for the caller to detect the end of the array.
- you return `*commands`, which is the first word, not the array of strings
- you cannot return a local array at it becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

Here is an alternative approach using standard string functions that avoid many of the above shortcomings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **commands(const char *command) {
    char **array;
    int count, pos, len;
    for (pos = 0, count = 0;; count++) {
        // skip whitespace
        pos += strspn(command + pos, " \t\r\n");
        if (command[pos] == '\0')
            break;
        // get the word length
        len = strcspn(command + pos, " \t\r\n");
        // skip the word
        pos += len;
    }
    // allocate memory for the array:
    array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * (count + 1));
    if (array == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (pos = 0, i = 0;; i++) {
        // skip whitespace
        pos += strspn(command + pos, " \t\r\n");
        if (command[pos] == '\0')
            break;
        // get the word length
        len = strcspn(command + pos, " \t\r\n");
        // make a copy of the word
        array[i] = strndup(command + pos, len);
        if (array[i] == NULL) {
            while (i-- > 0)
                free(array[i]);
            free(array);
            return NULL;
        }
        // skip the word
        pos += len;
    }
    array[i] = NULL;
    return array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t size = 0;
    char *user_input = NULL;
    char **user_commands;

    for (;;) {
        printf("witsshell> ");
        if (getline(&user_input, &size, stdin) < 0)
            break;
        char **user_commands = commands(user_input);
        if (user_commands) {
            for (int i = 0; user_commands[i]; i++) {
                printf("%d: %s\n", i, user_commands[i]);
                free(user_commands[i]);
            }
            free(user_commands);
        }
    }
    free(user_input);
    return 0;
}
```